cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTrees (in module jdk.compiler)
I have customized an annotation handler using java21. The pom file of the project where the annotation processor is located is shown below:
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>xxx-xx</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>xxx-xx-xx</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>async-log-client</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.auto.service</groupId>
            <artifactId>auto-service</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>21</source>
                    <target>21</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.model=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

I use the mvn clean instal command to package to a local repository. I get the following error when I use it as a dependency on other projects
class org.example.MyCustomProcessor (in unnamed module @0x3b48e183) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTrees (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.api to unnamed module @0x3b48e183

I tried importing jdk modules in the project that uses that custom annotation processor.
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>21</source>
          <target>21</target>
          <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
          <compilerArgs>
            <arg>--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
            <arg>--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
            <arg>--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
            <arg>--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
            <arg>--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.model=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
            <arg>--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
            <arg>--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
            <arg>--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
            <arg>--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
            <arg>--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
          </compilerArgs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

But it still doesn't seem to work. My goal is to build a lombok-like annotation processor project. Other projects can directly dependency on it to run the annotation processor。
Edit 1
Modify the compilation configuration in the POM that depends on this annotation processor
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>21</source>
                    <target>21</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-Xlint</arg>
                        <arg>-verbose</arg>
                        <arg>-XprintRounds</arg>
                        <arg>-XprintProcessorInfo</arg>
                        <arg>-Xmaxerrs</arg>
                        <arg>10000</arg>
                        <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

I tried to add <fork>true</fork> by reference here and although it compiles successfully, it causes the annotation processor to not work

This question is not a [lombok] question. The fact that you are trying to implement something "lombok like" is irrelevant to the question.  It won't alter the answer, and most likely won't be relevant to other people who are search to answer to a question about using com.sun.tools.javac classes in a non-modular post-Java 8 program.  (Which is the generalization of this question.)

In fact, I would like to know how lombook solved the problem of migration of annotation processor from java8 to java9+. I am trying to write the annotation processor in java21 and compile it into a jar package. When this jar package is depended on by other projects it reports an error

Since Lombok is open source, you can check yourself how they solved it.
